# Python: Allow object to be recreated from a serialised form without re-computing attributes

Tags: python, class, serialization, deserialization, python-dataclasses

Say I have a class like this:

```py
from uuid import uuid4 as uuid
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Link:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.id = str(uuid())
        self.content = self.scrape()

    def scrape(self):
        # get webpage
        response = requests.get(self.url).text
        # extract the text (excluding HTML tags etc)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response, features="html.parser")
        return soup.get_text()
```

Now, I can create a new instance of that class like so:

```py
>>> my_link = Link("https://example.com")
>>> my_link.id
'ba664ae1-eb5d-4370-9276-93f8d9d03a0d'
>>> my_link.content
'Example Domain Example Domain This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission. More information...'
```

But what if I already have the `id` and `content` attributes already stored in a database, and I want to recreate my object from its serialized form? I might have JSON like this:

```json
{
    "url": "https://example.com",
    "id": "ba664ae1-eb5d-4370-9276-93f8d9d03a0d"
    "content": "Example Domain Example Domain This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission. More information..."
}
```

Obviously, I could pass through these options in `__init__`:

```py
def __init__(self, url, id=None, content=None):
    self.url = url
    if id and content:
        self.id = id
        self.content = content
    else:
        self.id = str(uuid())
        self.content = self.scrape()
```

But this becomes unwieldy with more and more attributes, for instance if I wanted to add a `title` field, or I wanted to change to a `dataclass`.

What's the recommended way to do this?

Comment: @Carcigenicate That sounds like a good approach. Do you want to write an answer so I can give you some rep and mark it as accepted?

Comment: I realized that two aux initializers weren't necessary. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simplify your current `__init__` method to be the "simple" version (that takes pre-computed values as arguments) and define new class methods that, for example, compute a new UUID to pass to `__init__`, or extracts data from a `dict`, or parses a JSON value to create the `dict` to extract data from.

```
class Link:
    def __init__(self, url, str_uuid, content):
        self.url = url
        self.id = str_uuid
        self.content = content

    # Like most static methods, this may work just as well
    # as a regular function defined outside the class.
    @staticmethod
    def scrape(url):
        response = requests.get(url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response, feature="html.parser")
        return soup.get_text()

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, url):
        str_uuid = str(uuid())
        content = cls.scrape(url)

        return cls(url, str_uuid, content)

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, data):
        return cls(data['url'], data['id'], data['content'])

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, obj):
        return cls.from_dict(json.loads(obj))

l1 = Link.create("https://example.com")

json_obj = '''{
    "url": "https://example.com",
    "id": "ba664ae1-eb5d-4370-9276-93f8d9d03a0d"
    "content": "Example Domain Example Domain This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission. More information..."
}'''
l2 = Link.from_dict(json.loads(json_obj))

d = json.loads(json_obj)
l3 = Link.from_json(d)

l4 = Link(d['url'], d['id'], d['content'])
```

If you only need the URL the *first* time you create the object, you don't need to save it as an attribute. If you want an existing object to be able to "rescrape" a link, add an additional instance method:

```
def rescrape(self):
    self.content = self.scrape(self.url)
```

Answer (score 1):

I may just move the responsibility of scraping out of the initializer. Maybe have a static "aux initializer" that does the scraping to get the data.

```
class Link:
    def __init__(self, url, content=None):
        self.url = url
        self.id = str(uuid())
        self.content = content

    @staticmethod
    def from_scraped_data(url):
        link = Link(url)
        content = link.scrape()
        link.content = content
        return link

    def scrape(self):
        # get webpage
        response = requests.get(self.url).text
        # extract the text (excluding HTML tags etc)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response, features="html.parser")
        return soup.get_text()
```

The reassignment post object creation seems a tad hacky, but I think it's required with how things are set up. I might remove `scrape` altogether from the class, then do something like:

```
class Link:
    def __init__(self, url, link_id, content):
        self.url = url
        self.id = link_id
        self.content = content

    @staticmethod
    def from_scraped_data(url):
        content = scrape(url)
        return Link(url, str(uuid()), content)

def scrape(url):
    # get webpage
    response = requests.get(url).text
    # extract the text (excluding HTML tags etc)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, features="html.parser")
    return soup.get_text()
```

Which I think is better since it doesn't leave `link` in a bad state momentarily.

Comment: Could it make more sense to use `@classmethod`s? Use `__init__()` to create an object without scraping, and have a `from_url()` `classmethod` that scrapes?

Comment: Alternatively, might I want to have `__init__()` take a `mode` parameter, being either `"scrape"` or `"deserialize"`, and match that to one of two methods?

Comment: @amshepherd Either `staticmethod` or `classmethod` works here. And I already updated the last example to take all data via `__init__`, but forgot to update the first. I'll change that.

Comment: @amshepherd And no, I would not go in that direction. Having functions radically changing their behavior based on a flag is generally regarded as an anti-pattern. It's best to use two separate functions, and call the one that has the behavior you want. Or use something like the strategy pattern when that's appropriate.

Comment: Specifically, I think that would be a violation of SOLID's "open-close principle". You want code to be open to extension, but closed to changes. If you based behavior on a flag/enum and want to add cases in the future, you're suddenly needing to modify the function to add cases. In the extreme case of that, your function becomes basically a switch over different behaviors. It's best to move that decision making out so new cases can be added on the fly, and code external to the function decides which behavior is required.